# Convert an images pixel value from rgb to grayscale manually python PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, grayscale

Im trying to use a [specific gamma corrected grayscale implementation](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0029740) - Gleam to convert an images pixels to grayscale. How can i do this manually with PIL python?

```
def tau_gamma_correct(pixel_channel):
    pixel_channel = pixel_channel**(1/2.2)
    return pixel_channel

#@param: rgb
#@result: returns grayscale value
def gleam(rgb):
    #convert rgb tuple to list
    rgblist = list(rgb)
    #gamma correct each rgb channel
    rgblist[0] = tau_gamma_correct(rgblist[0])
    rgblist[1] = tau_gamma_correct(rgblist[1])
    rgblist[2] = tau_gamma_correct(rgblist[2])
    grayscale = 1/3*(rgblist[0] + rgblist[1] + rgblist[2])
    return grayscale

# get a glob list of jpg filenames
files = glob.glob('*.jpg')
for file in files:
    file = open(file)
    filename = file.name
    image = Image.open(file)
    pix = image.load()
    width, height = image.size
    #print(width,height)
    for x in range(0, width):
        for y in range(0, height):
            rgb = pix[x,y]
            #print(rgb)
            # calc new pixel value and set to pixel
            image.mode = 'L'
            pix[x,y] = gleam(rgb)

            image.save(filename + 'gray.gleam'+'.jpg')
   file.close()
```

`SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple`
It is still expecting the rgb tuple i think.

Comment: Try moving the `file.close()` 2 indent blocks back, and see it fixes the issue ? I mean moving the `file.close()` command as in the same indentation level as the `open()` method.

Comment: didnt help, the problem is im not sure how to change the rgb tuple to a single grayscale value. im trying to change the mode but it seems to not work or maybe it cant be changed. i will check the PIL docs.

Comment: isn't the `gleam` function returning a integer grayscale value between 0 and 255 ? Do you want a tuple returned by the function instead of integer ?

Comment: yeh thats what im aiming at..

Comment: i want to set the pixel value to the grayscale value instead of the rgb tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that i could just build another image:

```
import sys
import os
import glob
import numpy
from PIL import Image

def tau_gamma_correct(pixel_channel):
    pixel_channel = pixel_channel**(1/2.2)
    return pixel_channel

#@param: rgb
#@result: returns grayscale value
def gleam(rgb):
    #convert rgb tuple to list
    rgblist = list(rgb)
    #gamma correct each rgb channel
    rgblist[0] = tau_gamma_correct(rgblist[0])
    print('gleamed red ' + str(rgblist[0]))
    rgblist[1] = tau_gamma_correct(rgblist[1])
    print('gleamed green ' + str(rgblist[1]))
    rgblist[2] = tau_gamma_correct(rgblist[2])
    print('gleamed blue ' + str(rgblist[0]))
    grayscale = (rgblist[0] + rgblist[1] + rgblist[2])/3
    print('grayscale '+ str(grayscale))
    return grayscale

# get a glob list of jpg filenames
files = glob.glob('*.jpg')
for file in files:
    file = open(file)
    filename = file.name
    image = Image.open(file)
    pix = image.load()
    width, height = image.size
    new_image = Image.new('L', image.size)
    #pixelmatrix = [width][height]
    pixelmatrix = numpy.zeros((width, height))
    #print(width,height)
    for x in range(0, width):
        for y in range(0, height):
            rgb = pix[x,y]
            print('current pixel value: '+str(rgb))
            # calc new pixel value and set to pixel
            #print(gleam(rgb))
            gray = gleam(rgb)
            print('changing to pixel value: '+str(gray))
            pixelmatrix[x,y] = gray
            new_image.save(filename + 'gray.gleam'+'.jpg')
    new_image.putdata(pixelmatrix)
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `image.mode = 'L'` doesn't actually change the type of the image, it just changes the attribute so it's no longer accurate. To change the mode of the image you need to make a new copy with [`image.convert('L')`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.convert).

Once you have an image in grayscale mode, it won't require a tuple for a pixel value anymore.

Comment: thanks. tho seems that i need to process every pixel, its [good enough for me] to just build a grayscale from scratch. ie. i dont need to convert the original, i just need the grayscale. am having problems putting the numpy array/matrix data into the image tho.

Comment: @jsky you have two objects, `new_image` and `new_img`, you're probably just getting them confused.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the `SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple` error it seems that you need to return a tuple, which is represented as :

```
sample_tuple = (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

So we edit the `gleam()` function as:

```
def gleam(rgb):
    #convert rgb tuple to list
    rgblist = list(rgb)
    #gamma correct each rgb channel
    rgblist[0] = tau_gamma_correct(rgblist[0])
    rgblist[1] = tau_gamma_correct(rgblist[1])
    rgblist[2] = tau_gamma_correct(rgblist[2])
    grayscale = 1/3*(rgblist[0] + rgblist[1] + rgblist[2])
    return (grayscale, )
```

Keep in mind that while returning a single element tuple you need to represent as :

```
sample_tuple = (1, )
```

This is due to the fact that `(4) == 4` but `(4, ) != 4`